# Redirect to Modal dialog page oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page after process redirect to modal dialog page (tow page it's public) . the modal dialog only for alert ,and  i have a dynamic action in  modal page to close  and redirect to another web site   .

i have a problem the page always loading ,like a picture how i can solve this problem.
 i try it in other application it's work fine but i don't no what happened in this application

please any advise to solve this problem

[image: MODAL PAGE]

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools and go to the Console. Do you see any errors there? If so, what do they say?

Comment: thanks Dan , the issue has been solved , only i am copy the application and run the copy application in copy the issue not appear , i don't know what happen but  the issue solved .

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to open another site in iframe, it can be restricted by your application security policy:
Shared components -> Security Attributes -> Browser Security -> see "Embed in Frames"

You also can check your browser "Network" dev tools and APEX debug.

Comment: Oh, sorry for    misunderstanding   the redirect to web site working fine , but the redirect to modal page not working it always loading and after 10 second redirect to website.